# Missing vcxproj.filters files in projects converted from VS 2010 to VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am moving my solution to a TFS environment. 
several (8) "old" C++ projects that were created in VS 2010 and migrated to VS 2012 are missing the vcxproj.filters file.
These projects appear happy and content to live without the .filters, but when I try to add them to TFS 2012 from within visual studio (not from the external source control tool) in order to have a source-control binding in the project file, I get errors due to the missing filters file.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem? any solution?

thanks,

Comment: I wish the guy that did -1 on this would encounter the same problem. This sucks. I'm currently creating new project files manually copying the old ones to them (hoping I don't break something)

Comment: +1: I do not see anything wrong in this post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ok. so there is a very easy solution to this: just add a file filter (project -> add -> add new filter). this cause VS to create the filters file for you...

apparently this only happens if you don't have any filter (folder) in your project.